# C# double value returns NaN

Tags: c#

I have this code Here:

```
public double ProgressBar
{
    get
    {
        return ((double)Completed / Progress);
    }
}
```

But it always returns NaN when both values (Completed and Progress) are 0.

I have also tried:

```
public double ProgressBar
{
    get
    {
        return ((double)Completed / (double)Progress);
    }
}
```

Same result NaN

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: ? Progress := 0 ?

Comment: They both currently are 0 because I dont have any data. but I am expecting it to return 0.0 or even 0

Comment: lol yes, @MitchWheat is saying you probably divided by 0.

Comment: 0 / 0 = NaN ... X / 0 = NaN

Comment: return (Progress == 0) ? 0 : ((double)Completed / Progress);

Comment: @user979331 since when dividing by zero gives 0? Complaining about lack of DivideByZeroException would make sense... but demanding 0 as the result????

Comment: You get to define what `ProgressBar` gets to be when `Progress` is 0 (it's your code), but don't try dividing by zero

Comment: @MitchWheat To be clear, X/0 is NaN if X is zero, otherwise it is +ve or -ve infinity. (I realise your comment was assuming X is zero, but I just wanted to clarify for other readers)

Answer (score 7):

Dividing by zero is not allowed and thus should be avoided.

Per the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.dividebyzeroexception):

> Trying to divide an integer or `Decimal` number by zero throws a `DivideByZeroException` exception. To prevent the exception, ensure that the denominator in a division operation with integer or `Decimal` values is non-zero.
>
> Dividing a floating-point value by zero doesn't throw an exception; it results in positive infinity, negative infinity, or not a number (NaN), according to the rules of IEEE 754 arithmetic.

So if you want the result to be `0.0` if `Progress` is `0`, then you should express so explicitly in your code. For example like this:

```cs
public double ProgressBar
{
    get
    {
        return Progress == 0 ? 0.0 : ((double)Completed / (double)Progress);
    }
}
```